# SharePoint Organization Profiles

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

I noticed that SharePoint User Profile Service now includes a definition for Organization Profiles.  I think this is a really interesting new feature, but I'm not sure how it is used inside of SharePoint 2010.  I found some information concerning the people picker, but not much outside of that.

So I am wondering if anyone is using Organization Profiles and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to remember hearing that this is a feature that was supposed to more substantial but basically got cut from the 2010 release. So I don't think you can do much with them in this version of SharePoint.

Comment: That is what it seems like.

Comment: True this. The object model is there, but there is no implementation. If you want to use organization types, you must create your own controls for rendering and map them to AD

Answer (score 0):

Organization Profiles were not fully realized or documented in the 2010 system. If you're planning on using them, don't. They're deprecated in 2013 and no longer available so any investment today will be lost tomorrow in this space.