# can I create organization profiles manually, and add AD users to it?

Tags: profile-sync, user-profile-service, organization-browser

I have partners with an AD account in a specific OU (for authentication purposes).
The schema hasn't be customized.

using the SharePoint OM and/or BCS and/or profile sync, can I create partners company organisation profiles, and attach specific AD accounts ?

A former [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/sharepoint-organization-profiles) let me think I can, but with my own admin process, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to add all the plumbing to "hook up" the organization profiles.  The UI and some API stuff exist but it was never really finished.  That is to say, you can make it do whatever you like as long as you are willing to put in the work.

MS API Organization Profile Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.organizationprofile_members(office.14).aspx